# DNS/Apache config to change ServerName on Mac OS X and LAN

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, mac-osx, local-area-network

I want to run an apache web server on a machine running OS X, with the server running on a small intranet LAN with no internet connection. I've set up web sharing and the web server is now accessible from other machines on the LAN using the custom name a.local - but what I would like to do is remove the .local part if possible. Does anyone know how i would go about configuring this in OS X? I wasn't sure if it would be the apache httpd.conf file or some DNS config that would be required.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't a local DNS server running somewhere in your network (many routers offer this functionality), the only way would be to enter the IP address and host name in the hosts file of every computer in question.

The .local part is coming from [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)), by the way. And without Bonjour, you could access the machine only with it's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you could set up dns to host both domain "a" and machine "a" but that seems quirky to me. i would probably approach it this way: 1) configure dns for your network so that your server is called something like "a.nickyco.private" 2) in server admin, set up a website for "a.nickyco.private" 3) set up DHCP to provide a "search domain" to the clients of "nickyco.private" 4) you're done. you should be able to type "http://a" on the clients, and it will show you the website for "a.nickyco.private"